# App hangs when registering for context menu

Tags: android

In my webview, I want to open a context menu whenever there is a long click on any view.

**All my context menu related code:-**

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View view,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
  {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
      menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
      menu.add(0,view.getId(),0,"Save File");
      menu.add(0,view.getId(),0,"Show URL");
  }

/**
 * Context menu
 */
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if(item.getTitle()=="Save File")
    {   
        return true;
    }
    else if (item.getTitle()=="Show URL")
    {myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            myWebView.loadUrl(url); 
            // Here the String url hold 'Clicked URL' 
            displayMessage(url);
            return false; 
        } 
    });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I am doing this in onCreate()

```
this.registerForContextMenu(myWebView);
```

And the app force closes. Am I doing something wrong here, please point it out to me.

Comment: Please post the error log from Logcat

Comment: Its nullpointer exception, thats why I think I'm just making a small error, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Which line of code throw `NullPointerException`? There are many possibility that you have missed to give appropriate reference. Sometimes it may be a silly mistake somewhere that is obvious.

Comment: yeah, this one is, I am sure. Whenever I register the context menu in onCreate, its hangs and when i remove it, it works fine(ofcourse the context menu not works then).   So this code:- this.registerForContextMenu(myWebView);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
public void onCreateContentMenu
```

Should be this:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu
```

??

Comment: ok... just to be certain all bases are covered, you have the `registerForContextMenu` *after* you define `myWebView`?  And is the WebView inflated from XML or created programatiically?

Comment: I have defined 'myWebView' before onCreate(), as a class view. And it is inflated from XML.